# CardView and RecyclerView (Android 5.0)

Tags: android, material-design

I have Updated SDK 5.0 (API 21)[image]

But I am not able to find CardView and RecyclerView!
Help me. or send Link to find Both Library

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Anks please mark Ranjith answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the below image. from your sdk manager you will have to download the'Android Support Library'
[image]

and then in your dependencies of project you have to add

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Just add dependencies in build.gradle to add recylerview and cardview as below:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

It is also present in `extras/android/support/v7/` of your sdk installation path. Just import it in eclipse or in android studio.
[How to import in eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)